# why undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass error only when not following any user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit perplexed as to why the code works just fine when the user is "following" another person but it throws the error the error below when the user is following no one.

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#home 
undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass
```

Controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(page: params[:page]) 
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
      @items =  (@feed_items + @activities)
      @items.sort_by! {|item| -item.created_at.to_i}
     else
    redirect_to root_path  
    end
  end
```

I get the error when I try to use this in view (`views\shared\_items.html.erb`)

```
<%= link_to item.trackable.post.user.name, item.trackable.post.user %>
```

As I mentioned, it works with no errors when a user is "following" other users

Where should I look into for an error like this? I'm trying to figure out why if a user is not following anyone, this error is thrown.

Here's the full trace

```
app/views/shared/_item.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_shared__item_html_erb___832826646_61919064'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:351:in `block in collection_with_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:348:in `each'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:348:in `collection_with_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:250:in `render_collection'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:234:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:233:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:15:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb__744481885_62482392'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:38:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___504558116_37464468'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
sunspot_rails (2.0.0) lib/sunspot/rails/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__762502449__process_action__639804392__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__802127317__call__351719387__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here's what the overall structure of the view looks like (the error is caused by the very last codes)

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>

<% if item.class == PublicActivity::Activity %>
   <% if item.trackable_type == "Post" %>
      <%= link_to item.owner.name, item.owner if item.owner %><span class="textname"> posted </span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.</span>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to item.owner.name, item.owner if item.owner %><span class="textname"> made a comment </span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.</span>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
<br>
     <%= link_to item.user.name, item.user %>
      <span class="textname">shared this</span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.</span>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
<% if item.trackable_type == "Post" %>
  <%= link_to item.owner.name, item.owner if item.owner %><span class="textname"> posted </span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to item.owner.name, item.owner if item.owner %></span><span class="textname"> made a comment on <%= link_to item.trackable.post.user.name, item.trackable.post.user %> </span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.</span>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What's `item.trackable`? It's `nil` when a user is not "following" another user, from what I can infer from the code you've posted.

Comment: Even when a user is not "following" anyone, the user still has all of the @activities that show. When a user is following, then that is @feed_items+@activities together. @activities by itself should have `item.trackable`

Answer (score 0):

If your user is not following anything, I assume `trackable` is nil. If `trackable` is nil, then it can't have a `post`.

You might want to add a check for trackable;

```
if item.trackable.present?
  -- your code here --
else
  -- perhaps a message that nothing is tracked? --
```